# filter pandas dataframe by cell type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I have a geodataframe generated from openstreetmap data. I have an issue with one of the columns, which returns a `dtype` of `object`, containing a mix of strings and lists, as in the `highway` column below.

```
    access geometry                                         highway
0   NaN LINESTRING (-10817.60510122531 6680340.0880667...   footway
1   no  LINESTRING (-11843.46986863073 6678698.1663396...   footway
2   no  LINESTRING (-11843.46986863073 6678698.1663396...   [footway, steps]
3   no  LINESTRING (-11843.46986863073 6678698.1663396...   footway
4   NaN LINESTRING (-9727.497855683101 6679963.0804682...   unclassified
```

I'm trying to get the unique values of the `highway` column, but the `unique()` function returns a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error. I understand why this happens, but I'm not sure how to actually go about getting the unique values. I was thinking about filtering the dataframe by cell dtype, something like

`dfMultitags = df[type(df['highway']) == type(list()]`

but I can't seem to find a way to do that either. Any thoughts welcome.

**EDIT:**
This issue has more to do with pandas columns containing irregular lists, solutions from [Group operations on Pandas column containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635048/group-operations-on-pandas-column-containing-lists) don't apply neatly here. the answer there is to convert the list to tuple. In my case this results in the following:

```
0                      (f, o, o, t, w, a, y)
1                      (f, o, o, t, w, a, y)
2                           (footway, steps)
3                      (f, o, o, t, w, a, y)
4       (u, n, c, l, a, s, s, i, f, i, e, d)
5       (u, n, c, l, a, s, s, i, f, i, e, d)
6                      (f, o, o, t, w, a, y)
```

Ideally I would like to split the initial dataframe into two dataframes, one containing all cells of `list` type, the other containing all cells with `str` values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group operations on Pandas column containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635048/group-operations-on-pandas-column-containing-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply()` to convert only the lists to tuples while leaving the rest unchanged, then call `unique()`:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'highway': ['footway', 'footway', ['footway', 'steps'], 'footway', 'unclassified']})

In [16]: df['highway'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x).unique()
Out[16]: array(['footway', ('footway', 'steps'), 'unclassified'], dtype=object)
```

If you apply `tuple()` to the entire column, it converts the strings into tuples of each character.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `astype` convert to `str`, then `duplicated` data from @chrisz

```
df[~df.type.astype(str).duplicated(keep='first')]
Out[75]: 
              type
0  [highway, road]
1          highway
2    [road, other]
```