# Groupby id a column that contains lists

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

Suppose you have the following data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,0,1], 'lst':[["a", "b", "c"],["e"],["c"]]})
>>> df
  id         lst
0   0  [a, b, c]
1   0        [e]
2   1        [c]
```

And you wish to group the data by id as follows:

```
   id        lst
0   0  [[a, b, c], [e]]
2   1  [[c]]
```

Is there a way to group columns of lists, so one can obtain the results I present above?

I tried the solution posted at the following link: [Group operations on Pandas column containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635048/group-operations-on-pandas-column-containing-lists), But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# groupby id, then then apply list to the resulting grouped lst items

df.groupby('id')['lst'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

```
    id  lst
0   0   [[a, b, c], [e]]
1   1   [[c]]
```

Comment: @AndresPerez, not following you.  I used the data you shared and get the result matching the expected outcome. What you meant by *got the table*?